# Select query with same value in row

Tags: sql

I have a table structure like this:

```
order_item_id order_id product_id
1                513     120
2                213     121
3                513     120
4                312     131
5                312     131
6                102     123
```

I want to have a SQL query where I can get the following results:

```
order_item_id order_id product_id
1                513     120
3                513     120
4                312     131
5                312     131
```

I used the following SQL query to fetch the results, but it doesn't help:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `stg_83087_wc_order_product_lookup`
WHERE `order_id` = `order_id` and `product_id` = `product_id`
```

The only question I have to is to get the next value of the row so I can make the comparison here.

Comment: Oops sorry, I just added more details.

Comment: Just use an `exists` with the same table and look for rows with same the same content apart from the order_item_id.

Comment: Your code as it's now will return all rows, since you're comparing a value with  the same value.

Comment: What are your rules here?  where it occurrs twice? What about 3 times?  What's the business rule you're after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need to check the *exist*ance of similar rows:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
  select * from t t2
    where t2.order_id = t.order_id
      and t2.product_id = t.product_id
      and t2.order_item_id != t.order_item_id
);
```

Comment: Teaching use of poor aliases? :( Also, you need the product id to match.

Comment: Thanks I missed the second column, added. Using `t` is pretty common, not aiming to teach anything about aliases, I was writing the above before the OP included anything about a named table.